# How to find all rectangles in a PDF using iText

Tags: pdf, itext, rectangles

A MS word document with a text box(rectangle) and I have successfully used libreoffice convert it to PDF.
How should I find all text box(rectangle) in pdf and How interpret the coordinates of a rectangle?

```
@Override
public void modifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    if (renderInfo.getOperation() == PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT) {
        float x = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(0);
        float y = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(1);
        float w = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(2);
        float h = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(3);
        Vector a = new Vector(x, y, 1).cross(renderInfo.getCtm());
        Vector c = new Vector(x + w, y + h, 1).cross(renderInfo.getCtm());
```

implements ExtRenderListener, only allow find the page(A4) rectangle,do not find the (textbox)rectangle that contains all the content in a page.

Comment: What makes you think LibreOffice draws a rectangle using the rectangle operator? Maybe the rectangle was created using a move-to, four line-to, and one stroke operator.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. code example line-to or moe-to get rectangle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bruno pointed out, the problem is that you may be faced with rectangles that are only defined by line-to or move-to operations.

You will need to keep track of all line-drawing operations, and 'aggregate' them as soon as they intersect (whenever a line is being drawn whos end/start matches up with an already known line's end/start).

```java
public class RectangleFinder implements IEventListener {

    private Map<Line, Integer> knownLines = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> clusters = new HashMap<>();

    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if(data instanceof PathRenderInfo){
            PathRenderInfo pathRenderInfo = (PathRenderInfo) data;
            pathRenderInfo.preserveGraphicsState();
            Path path = pathRenderInfo.getPath();
            if(pathRenderInfo.getOperation() == PathRenderInfo.NO_OP)
                return;
            if(pathRenderInfo.getOperation() != PathRenderInfo.FILL)
                return;
            if(!isBlack(pathRenderInfo.getFillColor()))
                return;
            for(Subpath sPath : path.getSubpaths()){
                for(IShape segment : sPath.getSegments()) {
                    if(segment instanceof Line) {
                        lineOccurred((Line) segment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isBlack(Color c){
        if(c instanceof IccBased){
            IccBased col01 = (IccBased) c;
            return col01.getNumberOfComponents() == 1 && col01.getColorValue()[0] == 0.0f;
        }
        if(c instanceof DeviceGray){
            DeviceGray col02 = (DeviceGray) c;
            return col02.getNumberOfComponents() == 1 && col02.getColorValue()[0] == 0.0f;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void lineOccurred(Line line){
        int ID = 0;
        if(!knownLines.containsKey(line)) {
            ID = knownLines.size();
            knownLines.put(line, ID);
        }else{
            ID = knownLines.get(line);
        }

        Point start = line.getBasePoints().get(0);
        Point end = line.getBasePoints().get(1);
        for(Line line2 : knownLines.keySet()){
            if(line.equals(line2))
                continue;
            if(line2.getBasePoints().get(0).equals(start)
                    || line2.getBasePoints().get(1).equals(end)
                    || line2.getBasePoints().get(0).equals(end)
                    || line2.getBasePoints().get(1).equals(start)){
                int ID2 = find(knownLines.get(line2));
                clusters.put(ID, ID2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private int find(int ID){
        int out = ID;
        while(clusters.containsKey(out))
            out = clusters.get(out);
        return out;
    }

    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return null;
    }

    public Collection<Set<Line>> getClusters(){
        Map<Integer, Set<Line>> out = new HashMap<>();
        for(Integer val : clusters.values())
            out.put(val, new HashSet<Line>());
        out.put(-1, new HashSet<Line>());
        for(Line l : knownLines.keySet()){
            int clusterID = clusters.containsKey(knownLines.get(l)) ? clusters.get(knownLines.get(l)) : -1;
            out.get(clusterID).add(l);
        }
        out.remove(-1);
        return out.values();
    }

    public Collection<Rectangle> getBoundingBoxes(){
        Set<Rectangle> rectangles = new HashSet<>();
        for(Set<Line> cluster : getClusters()){
            double minX = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            double minY = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            double maxX = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
            double maxY = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for(Line l : cluster){
                for(Point p : l.getBasePoints()){
                    minX = Math.min(minX, p.x);
                    minY = Math.min(minY, p.y);
                    maxX = Math.max(maxX, p.x);
                    maxY = Math.max(maxY, p.y);
                }
            }
            double w = (maxX - minX);
            double h = (maxY - minY);
            rectangles.add(new Rectangle((float) minX, (float) minY, (float) w, (float) h));
        }
        return rectangles;
    }
}
```

This is a class I wrote to find black (filled) rectangles on a page.
With minor adjustments, it can find other rectangles as well.

Comment: Using `0f` as starting values for `maxX` and `maxY` is not a good idea, in particular if the visible page coordinates reach into negative values.

Comment: Feel free to edit the code. I merely posted something I had laying around, with the explicit warning it will probably need tweaking.

Comment: could you please provide this for c#

Answer (score 0):

Here is the c# 12 version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Data;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;
using Color = iText.Kernel.Colors.Color;

public class RectangleFinder : IEventListener
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Line, int> knownLines = [];
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> clusters = [];

    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (data is PathRenderInfo pathRenderInfo)
        {
            pathRenderInfo.PreserveGraphicsState();
            Path path = pathRenderInfo.GetPath();
            if (pathRenderInfo.GetOperation() == PathRenderInfo.NO_OP)
                return;
            if (pathRenderInfo.GetOperation() != PathRenderInfo.FILL)
                return;
            if (!IsBlack(pathRenderInfo.GetFillColor()))
                return;
            foreach (Subpath sPath in path.GetSubpaths())
            {
                foreach (IShape segment in sPath.GetSegments())
                {
                    if (segment is Line line)
                    {
                        LineOccurred(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsBlack(Color c)
    {
        if (c is IccBased col01)
        {
            return col01.GetNumberOfComponents() == 1 && col01.GetColorValue()[0] == 0.0f;
        }
        if (c is DeviceGray col02)
        {
            return col02.GetNumberOfComponents() == 1 && col02.GetColorValue()[0] == 0.0f;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void LineOccurred(Line line)
    {
        int ID;
        if (!knownLines.ContainsKey(line))
        {
            ID = knownLines.Count;
            knownLines.Add(line, ID);
        }
        else
        {
            ID = knownLines[line];
        }
        iText.Kernel.Geom.Point start = line.GetBasePoints()[0];
        iText.Kernel.Geom.Point end = line.GetBasePoints()[1];
        foreach (Line line2 in knownLines.Keys)
        {
            if (line.Equals(line2))
                continue;
            if (line2.GetBasePoints()[0].Equals(start)
                || line2.GetBasePoints()[1].Equals(end)
                || line2.GetBasePoints()[0].Equals(end)
                || line2.GetBasePoints()[1].Equals(start))
            {
                int ID2 = Find(knownLines[line2]);
                clusters[ID] = ID2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private int Find(int ID)
    {
        int output = ID;
        while (clusters.ContainsKey(output))
            output = clusters[output];
        return output;
    }

    public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<HashSet<Line>> GetClusters()
    {
        Dictionary<int, HashSet<Line>> output = [];
        foreach (int val in clusters.Values)
            output[val] = [];
        output[-1] = [];
        foreach (Line l in knownLines.Keys)
        {
            int clusterID = clusters.ContainsKey(knownLines[l]) ? clusters[knownLines[l]] : -1;
            output[clusterID].Add(l);
        }
        output.Remove(-1);
        return output.Values;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Rectangle> GetBoundingBoxes()
    {
        HashSet<Rectangle> rectangles = [];
        foreach (HashSet<Line> cluster in GetClusters())
        {
            double minX = double.MaxValue;
            double minY = double.MaxValue;
            double maxX = -double.MaxValue;
            double maxY = -double.MaxValue;
            foreach (Line l in cluster)
            {
                foreach (Point p in l.GetBasePoints())
                {
                    minX = Math.Min(minX, p.x);
                    minY = Math.Min(minY, p.y);
                    maxX = Math.Max(maxX, p.x);
                    maxY = Math.Max(maxY, p.y);
                }
            }
            double w = (maxX - minX);
            double h = (maxY - minY);
            rectangles.Add(new Rectangle((int)minX, (int)minY, (int)w, (int)h));
        }
        return rectangles;
    }
}
```